# Run Cloud Function to store Firebase Auth'ed user data to Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to create a front-end app with Firebase Authentication (Google sign-in) and Firebase Cloud Function which stores the authenticated user data to Firestore.

1. A user clicks a button to sign in with Google (Firebase Authentication).
2. The front-end calls Cloud Function (`saveAuthUserData`) after sign-in.
3. Cloud Function runs to store the authenticated user's profile in Firestore (collection: `users`).

The expected Cloud Function (3) is to send an HTTP POST request to Firestore with the user's profile data.

I wrote this `public/index.html` and `functions/index.js` (below), but still looking for the way how it should interact with Firebase without any errors, specifically how to send an HTTP POST request from `public/index.html` to Cloud Function in `functions/index.js`. Both files are deployed on Firebase Hosting.

`public/index.html`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup,GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxx",
    authDomain: "yyyyy.web.app",
    projectId: "zzzzzz"
};
const app = initializeApp(config);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth();
const functions = getFunctions();
var btn = document.getElementById("#sign-in-with-google");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
    var credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    var user = result.user;
    if(user !== null) {
        var profile = {
            email: user.email,
            name: user.displayName,
            uid: user.uid
        };
        const setAuthUserData = httpsCallable(functions, "setAuthUserData");
        setAuthUserData(profile).then((result) => {
            console.log(result.data);
        });
    }
});
```

`functions/index.js`

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();
const fireStore = admin.firestore();

const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

const setAuthUserData = async (profile) => {
    var isAuthUserSet = false;
    const db = fireStore.collection("users");
    const email = profile.email;
    if(email) {
        const ref = await db.doc(email).set(profile).then(() => {
            isUpdated = true;
      });
    }
  }
  return isUpdated;
}

app.post("/setAuthUserData/", (req, res) => {
  setAuthUserData(req.params.profile).then((response) => res.send(response));
});

const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
module.exports = { api };
```

**Updated on 9/6/2022**

I fixed my code as below by checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73625011/4922507), but I couldn't see any changes on Firestore and any success/error messages on both browser's console and GCP's Logs Explorer.

`functions/index.js`

- Cloud Function to save a user's profile data (being passed from `public/index.html`) to Firestore (`users` collection) if its email is valid.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
admin.initializeApp();
const fireStore = admin.firestore();

const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

module.exports.setAuthUserData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  var isUpdated = false;
  try {
      const db = fireStore.collection("users");
      const email = data.email;
      if(email) {
        const ref = await db.doc(email).set(data).then(() => {
          isUpdated = true;
        });
      }
      return isUpdated;
  } catch (err) {
      return err;
  }
});
```

[image]
[image]

Also, this terminal's screenshot shows how both functions and hosting are deployed.

[image]

Just in case, I tried to do the same thing without Cloud Function (as below) and it perfectly works as expected. When a user presses a button, he is asked to sign in with Google and his profile is properly stored in Firestore once authenticated.

`public/index.html`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxx",
    authDomain: "yyyyy.web.app",
    projectId: "zzzzzz"
};
const app = initializeApp(config);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = getAuth();
const functions = getFunctions();
var btn = document.getElementById("#sign-in-with-google");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result) => {
    var credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    var user = result.user;
    if(user !== null) {
        var profile = {
            email: user.email,
            name: user.displayName,
            uid: user.uid
        };
        (async() => {
            try {
                var profile = {
                    email: user.email,
                    name: user.displayName,
                    uid: user.uid
                };
                const ref = await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.email), profile);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        })();
    }
});
```

**Updated on 9/7/2022**

I fixed my code and finally it's working!
The reason why it hadn't been working is a few syntax errors in mine, and there is no problem in what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73625011/4922507).

Answer (score 1):

Since you do

```
const setAuthUserData = httpsCallable(functions, "setAuthUserData");
setAuthUserData(profile).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
    });
```

in your front-end, you need your Cloud Function to be of type [**Callable**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable);

Something along the following lines:

```
exports.setAuthUserData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        // Do whatever you need with userData, e.g. write to Firestore
        const db = fireStore.collection("users");
        const email = data.email;

        if (email) {
            const ref = await db.doc(email).set(data);
        };

        return { isUpdated: true }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        // Don’t do return error but look at the below URL for exact way to send the error to the front end
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quickest reply!
I applied this update to my code, but nothing had changed and Console doesn't show any success or error messages to help me find where I have to fix ...

Comment: GCP's Logs Explorer also doesn't show any logs related to `setAuthUserData`

Comment: Hi, see the updates to the code, in particular the two `console.log()`s

Comment: Thanks @renaud-tarnec! I updated the code with the given two `console.log()`s and clicked the button to sign in with Google, but no error messages could be confirmed on both browser's console and GCP Logs Explorer...

Comment: Can you add a `catch` block in the front-end as follows: `setAuthUserData(profile).then((result) => {console.log(result.data);}).catch(error =>  {console.log(error);});`

Comment: Hi @Renaud-Tarnec, thank you again for your follow-up on my duplicated post. I deleted it, and could you check the appended "Updated" section with my following work to the original post? (And, is this properly how it should be?)

Comment: Please update the cloud function code with the updated code in my answer. Note that there was an error In the initial code: the `profile` variable is undefined. What’s weird is that you should have seen an error in the Cloud Functions log.  Also, why do you do `module.exports.setAuthUserData` and not `exports.setAuthUserData`

Comment: Also can you share your `package.json` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247831/discussion-between-cultureshock-and-renaud-tarnec).